# Delphi - Use an existing automation object in a new application

Tags: delphi, object, automation

I've got an existing application which has an an automation object.
I have to rewrite this application, and I would like to use the existing automation object in the new application.

Is this possible somehowm, or do I have to create a new automation object in the new application and copy-paste the functions from the old one?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What Delphi version are you on?

Comment: Hey, the old application is Delphi 7, the new one is on Delphi 2009

Comment: By automation object you mean a OLE object or just a delphi Object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not need to re-write the automation object, and you can keep the old one, as long as it is running properly.

Re-writing working code is necessary only if you want to extend the functionality, or overcome incompatibility with new versions of the OS.  Otherwise it is plainly risky.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do I include the existing automation object in a new application?
I'ts not clear to how that is done in the IDE.

Comment: Rename the old .tlb file to <newproject>.tlb.  In the new project souce, add {$R *.tlb}.  Also, add the old project's  _TLB.pas file, renamed as <new project>_TLB.pas to the new project.  Then close and reopen the new project.  With luck, the TLB should then be available under View/Type Library.  You might receive errors because the interface implementation pas files will be missing.